# Undefined variable: num

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a simple login system and i am querying to see if the username the user has supplied exists in the database.However i am having trouble fetching the rowcount.İ keep getting undifined variable num: error.I also tried using,

```
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
```

However then i get the  Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object error.I am very new to php and web development and this confused me and i don't know how to get it working can someone please help me? Here is the code for the db.php file

```
<?php
require "config.php";


function DBconnect($config) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $config['database'],
                        $config['username'],
                        $config['password']);

        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $conn;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return $stmt;
}
```

And here is the code for the index.php file which is the login page.

```
<?php

// Allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
session_start();

// include the necessary files
require "db.php";
require "functions.php";
include "index.view.php";


//conect to the database so we can check, edit or ,data to our users table
$conn = DBconnect($config);

// if the user has submitted the form
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

    //protect the posted value then store them to variables
    $username = protect($_POST["username"]);
    $password = protect($_POST["password"]);

    //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
    if ( !$username || !$password ){
        // if not display an error message.
        echo "You need to fill in a username and password!";
    }else
        // if correct continue cheking

        //select all the rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
        query(  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                array("username" => $username),
                $conn);
        $num = $stmt->fetchColumn(); 


        //check if there was not a match
        if( $num == 0) {
            //if not display an error message
            echo "The username you entered does not exist!";
        }else{
            //if there was a mactch continue chekcing

            //select all rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
            query( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =:username && password = :pasword",
                    array("username" => $username, "password" => $password ),
                    $conn);
            $num = $stmt->fetchColumn();    

            //check if there was not a match
            if( $num == 0) {
                //if not display error message
                echo "Username and password do not mactch";
            }else {
                //if there was continue checking

                //split all the fields from the correct row into an associative array
                $row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                //check to see if the user has not activated their account
                if($row["active"] != 1) {
                    //if not display an error message
                    echo "You have not yet activated your account!";
                }else {
                    //if so then log them in

                    // set the login session storing their id. We use this to
                    // see if they are logged in or not.
                    $_SESSION["uid"] = $row["id"];
                    //show message confirming that they are loggd in
                    echo "You have succesfully logged in!";
                    //update the online field to 50 seconds in the future
                    $time = date("u")+50;
                    query( "UPDATE users SET online = :time WHERE id = :id",
                            array("time" => $time, "id" => $_SESSION["uid"]),
                            $conn);
                    //redirect them to the usersonline page
                    header("Location: usersOnline.php");
                }
            }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to grab `$stmt` as the return value of `query()`. Change the calls to :

```
$stmt = query(....);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
```

---

Please note that it is considered unsecure to give a detailed notice about

- the username was wrong
- the password was wrong
- both is wrong.

If you do so, it is easy for an attacker to get valid usernames. Onece having the usernames it requires much less effort to get the password for a valid account.

Also I would not use `rowCount()` for that as the number of rows will not be returned by every database driver. So the code could fail if you are once using a different database.

Change thg query to:

```
SELECT count(*) AS number_of_rows, * FROM users WHERE username =:username && password = :pasword"
```

... then fetch 'number_of_rows' from the result set:

```
if ( !$username || !$password ){
    // if not display an error message.
    echo "You need to fill in a username and password!";
}else

    //select the number of rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
    query(  "SELECT count(*) as number_of_records, * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password",
            array("username" => $username, "password" => "$password"),
            $conn);
    $record = $stmt->fetch();
    if($record['number_of_records'] !== '1') {
        echo 'wrong username and / or password';
    }
}
```

Further note: **DO NEVER STORE UNENCRYPTED PASSWORDS IN A DATABASE**

Instead you should store passwords hashed by a *salted* one way hash function like sha1 or md5. For brevity I'll not give an example here. I would google this or ask another question on SO.

Comment: thanks i tried that but then i get the [Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\wamp\www\sideProjects\loginTut\db.php on line 21] error :S  i also get the  PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\sideProjects\loginTut\db.php on line 21 error and i can't figure out what they mean:S

Comment: @Brock90 Hey, have to leave now from the computer. Can help you with the syntax errors later if you want. During this you should try yourself ;). Drop a comment here if you have further question.. see u

Comment: Thank you for your help i got the page to work but i want to ask do you know of a better way for showing errors instead of echo.i tried putting an empty array on the top of the page $data = array(); and then changing all the echo "....." to $data["status"] = "......" and on my view page i did <? if isset($stsus) : ?><P><?= $status; ?></p> <?php endif; ?> but for some reason it doesn't work.And thanks for your help.

Comment: Use something like `if (isset($data['status'])) { echo $data['status']; }` ... Note that `status` is an index of `$data` (as you told)

Answer (score 1):

Your `query()` function returns a statement, but you are not saving the return value from where you are calling it.

Change

```
query(.....);
```

to

```
$stmt = query(.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't stand such a bloated code. 
So, here is a proper version, without all useless and unnecessary and erroneous code:

```
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $sql = "SELECT id,active FROM users WHERE username=? && password=?";
    $stm = query($sql, array($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]), $conn);
    $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(!$row) {
        echo "Username and password do not mactch";
    } elseif($row["active"] != 1) {
        echo "You have not yet activated your account!";
    } else {
        $_SESSION["uid"] = $row["id"];
        $time = date("u")+50;
        $sql  = "UPDATE users SET online=? WHERE id=?";
        query($sql, array($time, $row["id"]), $conn);
        header("Location: usersOnline.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```